# PS Stop-Process fails to stop a subprocess launched from cmd.exe

Tags: windows, powershell, process, windows-command-prompt, pid

*Preface: I've boiled down a problem I'm having to this simple reproduction, which admittedly looks pretty strange out of context.*

From powershell (PS), if I use `Start-Process` to start notepad and capture the process ID, I can kill it with `Stop-Process`, no problem:

```
PS > $x = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru
...
PS > Stop-Process $x.id
```

I can do the same with `cmd.exe`, again without problem:

```
PS > $x = Start-Process cmd.exe -PassThru
...
PS > Stop-Process $x.id
```

Looking at TaskManager, this actually launches two processes: cmd.exe and [conhost.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/27347/what-is-the-conhost-exe-process-that-shows-up-in-task-manager). The PID returned from `Start-Process` belongs to cmd.exe, and killing it via `Stop-Process` terminates both.

*However* if I start a long-running sub-process like `ping -t 127.0.0.1` within the console, stopping with `Stop-Process` kills cmd.exe, conhost.exe, but *leaves the window with ping.exe running, as if nothing was killed.*

If instead I use `taskkill /PID <process-id>` or terminate the process  from TaskManager, all three processes (cmd, conhost, and ping) are terminated as expected.

#### Question

Why doesn't `Stop-Process <pid>` terminate the process in the same way as `taskkill /PID <pid>`? Is there any way to get `Stop-Process` to terminate `cmd.exe` and the long-running `ping` subprocess?

#### Repro

Start cmd.exe from powershell and note the PID.

```
PS > $x = Start-Process cmd.exe -PassThru
PS > $x.id
23652
```

From the command prompt, start a long-running subprocess like ping:

```
> ping -t 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
...
```

Open Task Manager and note the processes created in the same tree as ping.exe. For me these are:

```
Windows Command Processor 
   23652 cmd.exe 
   25260 conhost.exe
   22140 PING.EXE
```

Attempt to terminate via the process id returned from `Start-Process`:

```
PS > Stop-Process 23652
```

At this point, cmd.exe and conhost.exe are terminated, but TaskManager still shows `ping` running as a top-level process.

```
TCP/IP Ping Command   PING.EXE  22140
```

and the command prompt window remains, with the title `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - ping -t 127.0.0.1`.

Type CTRL+C from the "command prompt". PING will stop, and the window will disappear.

Comment: Maybe related. Seems to indicate `-Force` switch should send SIGKILL, but adding this switch doesn't change the observed behavior - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13664

Comment: [MS taskkill reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank you, your description above put me into the right direction for solving my problem.

So I dug into your question:

> Why doesn't Stop-Process  terminate the process in the same way as taskkill /PID ?

I'm not sure, I can't find any documentation on it, but considering my testing it simply does not stop any child processed that are still running, and in your testing a child process in created for ping.exe which is obviously still running.

> Is there any way to get Stop-Process to terminate cmd.exe and the long-running ping subprocess?

Yes, but not in one go. In your test setup, running the following command would show you all child processes:

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessId ='$($x.id)'" | Select-Object ParentProcessId,ProcessId,CommandLine`

Using Stop-Process with the output from ProcessId would kill all the child process and as killing the conhost process would also kill the cmd process this would do it.

The command below would do it all in one go:

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessId ='$($x.id)'" | Select-Object ParentProcessId,ProcessId,CommandLine | ForEach-Object {Stop-process $_.processId}`

Just as:
`taskkill /pid $x.id /t /f`

Comment: Thanks so much for digging in. Your solution worked for me in my repro example, and I think the approach of iterating over child processes will work for my original use case as well (launching detached processes from python).

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: I found a related solution on SO which uses a [recursive function to stop the entire process tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942155/1174169), which should kill grand-child processes as well.

Comment: Also related: [killing all processes whose parent process no longer exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991520/1174169). However, the solution is non-recursive and would terminate *all* process without a parent, including ones you didn't start yourself.